# Recurring Subscriptions with PayPal API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am currently trying to implement recurring subscriptions in an Asp.Net MVC Application. I have managed to make some progress: create a plan, set up an agreement and subscribe. This, as I understood should have set the plan into action. The first payment has been taken, and the account which was used to pay will be billed again on the next occurrence, in my case after a month has passed. I imagine, the required information should be recorded on the first payment, so when further notifications are received, the system can be configured to associate them with a particular user and apply the required changes to the system, for e.g. re-subscribe the user and extend his/her access to the service/s supplied by the web site.

I have a few questions which I hope someone with some more experience than me can answer:

1. Is the PayPal API, the correct technology to use to implement recurring subscriptions? Or have I gone for the wrong, possibly old, implementation?
2. Are Webhooks to be used so as to receive a notification when the
   user is billed over cycles? For e.g. to send a notification to the system once every month when the user is billed for the services?
3. What is the difference between these 2 Webhooks?
   PAYMENT.ORDER.CREATED and PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED?
4. Can the same Plan be re used for different Agreements? I imagine so, mainly because I do not think creating a new identical plan everytime makes sense: in my opinion it should be the Agreement that is created per user.
   However, every implementation I found created a new Plan every time the
   subscription process is initiated for a different user. I was
   wondering whether this was just for demonstration
   means in every case, or if there was a reason behind it.

The documentation I found is limited, and most often not substantiated with examples. Trying to combine different sources to get the information I want is proving to be a rather difficult task. Someone's experience in using the PayPal API for recurring subscriptions would therefore be most appreciated.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this hence why I'm commenting rather than a definitive answer but I hope this helps. (1) REST-API - Yes (2) Yes (3) i _think_ created happens before capture is completed so they are different steps in the 'flow' (4) Yes, have a plan for each subscribed element then users have agreements set up based on it.

Comment: In addition, i remember the API being a bit of an uphill struggle to integrate but once I got it working it was ok.

Comment: So I understand that the Webhook callback should be used to update the system's logic when the different events occur, both when creating the agreement for a particular user and getting the first payment, as well as when receiving notifications arising from monthly billing (and even failure cases, of course). I guess I'll have to try some things out and see how it goes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I remember when i set it up i had some test plans which were daily charges so i could verify the ongoing payments and webhook was working.

Comment: Great idea. I'll try it out!

Comment: Are you sure that the Webhook events mentioned in 3) are fired when automatic monthly payments are affected? This question, asked 2 years ago suggests that the feature was not available at that time, and was wondering whether you implemented it afterwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997063/paypal-webhook-for-billing-agreement-payment-received?rq=1